# Strange behaviour with Tikz

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I have recently been trying to format my science assignment in LaTeX. I tried to make a flowchart using Tikz, succeeding but only to find that the flowchart went slightly off the right of the page. Please do not be too critical for I picked up LaTeX quickly to do my science assignment.

Code for Tikz Diagram and Preamble:

Preamble:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{report}

\title{Year 9 Science Assignment}
\author{James Balajan}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Science.bib}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, decorations.pathreplacing, decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]
\tikzstyle{default} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=white!30]:
```

Diagram:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

    \node (1) [default] {Sodium Potassium mixture comes into contact with water};
    \node (2) [default, below of=1] {Electrons released, positively charged atoms remain};
    \node (3) [default, below of=2] {Positvely atoms are pushed away from each other due to electrostatic forces, creating spikes, exposing new electrons to the water};
    \node (4) [default, below of=3] {Other electrons leave the atoms leaving more positively charged atoms, creating more spikes};
    \node (5) [default, below of=4] {The cycle of electrons escaping leaving positively charged atoms continues till it eventually builds up enough heat to ignite the hydrogen gas};
    \draw [arrow] (1) -- (2);
    \draw [arrow] (2) -- (3);
    \draw [arrow] (3) -- (4);
    \draw [arrow] (4) -- (5);

  \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `align=center` to the `default` style which defines how the text should be aligned (left, right etc. is also possible)

Then either add line breaks manually to the text, or you can define a `text width=8cm` so that TikZ will break the lines according to that width.

Here is an example

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{arrow/.style = {thick,->,>=stealth},
         default/.style = {rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center,text width=8cm, draw=black, fill=white!30}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

    \node (1) [default] {Sodium Potassium mixture comes into contact with water};
    \node (2) [default, below of=1] {Electrons released, positively charged atoms remain};
    \node (3) [default, below of=2] {Positvely atoms are pushed away from each other due to electrostatic forces, creating spikes, exposing new electrons to the water};
    \node (4) [default, below of=3] {Other electrons leave the atoms leaving more positively charged atoms, creating more spikes};
    \node (5) [default, below of=4] {The cycle of electrons escaping leaving positively charged atoms continues till it eventually builds up enough heat to ignite the hydrogen gas};
    \draw [arrow] (1) -- (2);
    \draw [arrow] (2) -- (3);
    \draw [arrow] (3) -- (4);
    \draw [arrow] (4) -- (5);

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

[image]